# How to remount /home and etc... with Virtual machine

Tags: mount, vmware, home-directory

So on one of my machines running windows...
I have Vmware running Ubuntu

I was wondering if it were possible to:

1. Remount Full Client /home/user → Host RW /users/Windows_User_Directory; So that all Ubuntu home/user/downloads write to Windows /user/downloads ; Same with documents and etc...
2. OR remount any under /home/ (in the event that full home cannot be mounted)
3. OR Can the home directory or sub directories be mounted on a realtime compressed archive. (like a compressed downloads folder)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Shared Folders feature of VirtualBox. If you open this tab of the machine settings, you can add folders either permanently or just until the VM shuts down.

You need VirtualBox Extensions installed in the VM. Then you can just mount the shared folder as a special filesystem.

For example, if you've added `C:\Users\TardisGuy` as a shared folder named `TardisGuy` then inside the VM you can do:

```
mount -t vboxsf TardisGuy /home/tardisguy
```

You can also add a line to `/etc/fstab` as:

```
# <file system>  <mount point>    <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
TardisGuy        /home/tardisguy  vboxsf  defaults   0       0
```

NB: `vboxsf` is not a typo. It stands for VBOX Shared Folder not VBOX File System.